# Gzip/Deflate for CSS from PHP script

Tags: php, .htaccess, gzip

PHP file generate CSS content, like:

```
<php echo 'body {color:white}'; ?>
```

I call this from header like:

```
<link rel='stylesheet'  href='/style.php' type='text/css' />
```

How I can enable Gzip/Deflate compression for this file? (the main goal is to pass Google PageSpeed Insights test).

I try this code in .htaccess, but it's not working for this file.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    # DEFLATE by extension
    AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
</IfModule>
```

Also I try to add `header("Content-type: text/css;");` to php file, but it's not working too.

Comment: The `text/css` header is mainly for the browser's benefit. The server still knows the content is a PHP file and you therefore need to enable output compression on the PHP end rather than the Apache end. Check http://php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this code to the header of style.php helped me:

```
ini_set("zlib.output_compression", "On");
ini_set("zlib.output_compression_level", "-1");
if(!ini_get(‘zlib.output_compression’)) ob_start(«ob_gzhandler»);
```